# JQuery .fadeIn not working on my site

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I know this probably seems repetitive, but I can't get jQuery working on my site. I have looked through a lot of posts on here, but still can't seem to find the answer.

Here is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Rodeo Rich's Steakhouse</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Holtwood+One+SC" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<header>
    <a href="index.html"><img src="img/logo.png" id="logo" alt="Rodeo Rich's Steakhouse"></a>
</header>
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="menu.html">MENU</a></li>
        <li><a href="story.html">OUR STORY</a></li>
        <li><a href="giftcards.html">GIFT CARDS</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">CONTACT US</a></li>
    <ul>
</nav>
<img src="img/logo.png" id="pic" alt="Rodeo Rich's Steakhouse">
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the code from my JavaScript file that isn't doing anything to "#pic":

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#pic").fadeIn("slow");
});
```

1. I know that my path name to the .js file is correct
2. I have the Google CDN in my  section as well.

All help will be greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: If you open up your browser's debugging tool, and switch to network, do you get a 404 on any of your .js files? Does the console throw any errors?

Comment: you can't fadeIn something that's already visible.

Comment: @KevinB Did you downvote all the answers? :/

Answer (score 0):

Your image has to be hidden before it can fade in, so for example you can do:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#pic").hide().fadeIn("slow");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to hide your image in first (with CSS [`display:none`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display) or with jQuery [`.hide`](http://api.jquery.com/hide)).

This works:

```
$('#pic').hide();

$('button').click(function () {
    $('#pic').fadeIn('slow');
});
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/5vzgkpfx/1)**</kbd>